# A modelling question about point processes with heavy tails

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-process, point-process

I am trying to model a number of point processes for which I have data. If I choose to model each one using a (different) homogeneous Poisson process and estimate the rate using MLE then for some of the processes the goodness of fit is quite good. However for others it isn't and when I plot a histogram of the interarrival times, I see that they look exponential at first but then have a long tail that the Poisson process doesn't explain.

Naively I would like to try a model where the interarrival times are heavy tailed. However I understand this is no longer a Poisson process but rather a renewal process now. Is there some way to do MLE (or similar) to estimate the parameters of a renewal process so I can then do a goodness of fit test to see how plausible the model is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natural generalisation consists of using the Gamma distribution for modelling the increments ([Gamma process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_process)). This gives you more flexibility on the shape and tails in the distribution of the increments. Be careful about the type of distribution you use for modelling the increments since (i.) Not any distribution induces a Levy process, and (ii.) Things can get very complicated (See Section 3.2 of http://web.univ-pau.fr/~smercie1/Conferences/Symposium%202009%20MeierHirmer_Mercier_Roussignol.pdf and the references therein).

Given that the exponential distribution is a particular case of the Gamma distribution, you can compare the fit of these two models using AIC or BIC.